# Why are the wrong clusters projected onto PCA using Sklearn?

Tags: python, scikit-learn, cluster-analysis, pca

I am projecting my cluster centers onto 2 principal components, but the plot given is not in the correct central place of my 2 sets of data points. My code is given below. Does anyone see where I am going wrong? The PCA is fine, but one of the data points for the cluster is way off. I will mention that half of my centroid data points are negative. I have played around with inversing the pca transform and really am not sure where the error is coming from. Any help is greatly appreciated!

```
import numpy as np
import sklearn
from sklearn.cluster import KMeans
from sklearn.decomposition import PCA
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


data = normalize(key) 

key_N=normal(key,key)

pca=PCA(n_components=21)
pca.fit(data[:,0:-1])
keytrain_T = pca.transform(data[:,0:-1])

kmeans = KMeans(n_clusters=2, init='k-means++', n_init=100, max_iter=300, 
            tol=0.0001, precompute_distances='auto', verbose=0, random_state=None, copy_x=True, n_jobs=1)
kmeans.fit(data[:,0:-1])

centroid = cluster_centers_
print("The centroids:",centroid)

# Project the cluster points to the two first principal components
clusters = pca.fit_transform(centroid)

print("The clusters:",clusters)
```

Comment: Can you post the image?

Comment: I dont have enough points for that...

Comment: You can just post a link to imgur...

Comment: http://imgur.com/Xe4vXH9

Answer (score 1):

You `fit_transform` the centroids instead of `transform`ing them.

Comment: I need four final points, from my 21 dimensional cluster centers. When I used transform the graph still appears the same, and my clusters come out with: ''The clusters: [[ -3.73604149e-01  -7.88968144e-02  -2.39775253e-04  -2.98255905e-03
   -5.53224119e-03  -3.71999147e-03  -2.40050141e-03  -3.85699695e-04
    6.72346604e-03   4.83367176e-03   7.86504453e-04  -3.69889640e-03
    3.47965218e-04  -3.10482175e-03  -1.61504788e-03   1.68468915e-03
   -9.73136520e-04   5.83231053e-04  -8.74801939e-04  -2.84281009e-04
   -2.53746653e-04]'' (for 2 clusters)

Comment: With fit_transform it becomes: ''The clusters: [[ -1.35841000e+00   4.29736603e-16] [  1.35841000e+00   4.29736603e-16]]''

Comment: The graph has two has basically two rough centers of points that are even. The clusters should be in the middle of each, but one is completely out of the center...

Comment: Please let me know what you think!

Comment: Also, what are the reasons this can occur? Is it due to overfitting?

Comment: You should not reason solely on the shape. Think about what ``transform`` does vs what ``fit_transform`` does. You want ``transform``.  You set n_components=21, so you get a 21 dimensional vector out.

Comment: Have you seen the plot?

Comment: Have you seen my comment?

Comment: Yes I have :) I just do not see why, even when I change from 'fit_transform' and 'transform' the clusters stay pretty much the same, and are incorrect...

Comment: You haven't posted you plotting code, so it is hard to say what is going on there.

Comment: http://imgur.com/gallery/yMtro/new Here's all the code :) Thank you for helping! @AndreasMueller

Comment: Because of the plot? Shouldn't the cluster centres be in the middle of the data points?

Comment: They should be in the original space, that doesn't mean that is the case for any projection.